# $filter by nested object values only

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter

I am filtering JSON data against an array of strings. An example of `$scope.Data` is below:

```
{
    "exerciseDescription": "Lean forward onto a chair and allow the arm to hang down, gently swing the arm from side to side",
    "exerciseID": "324",
    "exerciseName": "Shoulder Pendular Exercise (Adduction/Abduction)",
    "images": [
        1008,
        1009,
        1010
    ],

    "tags": [
        "Body Part",
        "Arm",
        "Upper body",
        "Equipment",
        "Chair"
        "Soft Tissue"
    ]
},
```

There is a total of 4500 sets of this data and I would like to filter it by clicking on checkboxes. On clicking a checkbox I push the value of the checkbox (which will be a `tag`) to an array.

I would then like to filter against ONLY the the nested tag values.

My watch function is here:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('ActiveFilters', function(newValue) {
      if ($scope.ActiveFilters.length > 0) {
        $scope.FilteredData = $scope.Data;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.ActiveFilters.length; i++) {
          $scope.FilteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.FilteredData, $scope.ActiveFilters[i]);
          console.log($scope.FilteredData);
          // console.log($scope.ActiveFilters);
        }
      }
      else {
        $scope.FilteredData = [];
      }
    });
```

So if `$scope.FilteredData contains any 'ActiveFilters' in its nested`tag` array then it will show in the scope.

In brief - how can I only filter against the nested tag array.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering by an value of object in array in javascript:

```
var items = [{
    "exerciseDescription": "Lean forward onto a chair and allow the arm to hang down, gently swing the arm from side to side",
    "exerciseID": "324",
    "exerciseName": "Shoulder Pendular Exercise (Adduction/Abduction)",
    "images": [
        1008,
        1009,
        1010
    ],

    "tags": [
        "Body Part",
        "Arm",
        "Upper body",
        "Equipment",
        "Chair",
        "Soft Tissue"
    ]
}];

var filter = function (obj) {
  if (obj['tags'].indexOf("Soft Tissue") != -1) { // <--- filter by value in tags array
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var filtered = items.filter(filter);
```

I think you will get the idea and adapt it to use with angular.

Comment: Would ideally like an angular specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good reason to use `$filter` unless you're trying to filter in your AngularJS markup/templates. It's only really useful in JS if you want to support AngularJS filter expressions in custom directives.

Here's a more complete example for doing a tag filter in vanilla JavaScript:

```
var filterTags = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
var incomingData = [ // simplified example
  {id: 'banana', tags: ['foo', 'qux']},
  {id: 'potato', tags: ['qux', 'baz', 'foo', 'bar']},
  {id: 'carrot', tags: ['qux', 'quux']},
  {id: 'cabbage', tags: ['foo', 'baz', 'bar']}
];

var dataMatchingAllTags = incomingData.filter(function (obj) {
  return filterTags.every(function (tag) {
    return obj.tags.indexOf(tag) !== -1;
  });
}); // [{id: 'potato', …}, {id: 'cabbage', …}]

var dataMatchingAnyTag = incomingData.filter(function (obj) {
  return filterTags.some(function (tag) {
    return obj.tags.indexOf(tag) !== -1;
  });
}); // [{id: 'banana', …}, {id: 'potato', …}, {id: 'cabbage', …}]

var dataMatchingTagsExactly = incomingData.filter(function (obj) {
  return (
    obj.tags.length === filterTags.length &&
    filterTags.every(function (tag) {
      return obj.tags.indexOf(tag) !== -1;
    })
  );
}); // [{id: 'cabbage'}]
```

In your case `$scope.ActiveFilters` would be `filterTags`, `$scope.Data` would be `incomingData` and `$scope.FilteredData` would be either of `dataMatchingAllTags`, `dataMatchingAnyTag` or `dataMatchingTagsExactly`, depending on how you want the filters to work.

Note that this example assumes ES5 but considering AngularJS does so as well, I don't think this will be a problem.